# XmlSlurper.parse(uri) with HTTP basic authentication

Tags: groovy, basic-authentication, xmlslurper

I need to grab a data from XML-RPC web-service.

`new XmlSlurper().parse("http://host/service")` works fine, but now I have a particular service that requires basic HTTP authentication.

How can I set username and password for `parse()` method, or modify HTTP headers of the request?

Using `http://username:password@host/service` doesn't help - I still get `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL` exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found [this code over here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/view.groovy?id=38001) which might help?

Editing this code to your situation, we get:

```
def addr       = "http://host/service"
def authString = "username:password".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()

def conn = addr.toURL().openConnection()
conn.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "Basic ${authString}" )
if( conn.responseCode == 200 ) {
  def feed = new XmlSlurper().parseText( conn.content.text )

  // Work with the xml document

} else {
  println "Something bad happened."
  println "${conn.responseCode}: ${conn.responseMessage}" 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work for you

Please remember to use this instead of the 'def authString' mentioned above:

```
def authString  = "${usr}:${pwd}".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
```

Comment: I defined my parameters as usr and pwd.  Cheers!